# Ways to define CSS variables from JSON file or from typescript files?

Tags: css, angular, sass, webpack, css-variables

I want to define CSS variables like in Sass.
Something like:

```
.someClass {
  background-image: $imageLink;
  color: $someColor;
}
```

And i Want to define $imageLink and $someColor in my class or in json file.

Can i do this without Sass or Less? (Or without css variables, because it does not supported in IE.)

I an using angular2 and webpack in my project.

Comment: You could use http://cssnext.io/ but it's still using "something", you can't without any other tools as not supported yet.

Comment: Can you provide a case study of why you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you cannot set SASS variables at run-time, because by that time the SASS has already been compiled.

A classic approach is to instead think in terms of "themes", and select a theme by a class on a higher-level element (such as body). So you could have

```
.darktheme  .someClass { color: white; }
.lighttheme .someClass { color: black; }
```

Now from your JS you can change the theme with

```
document.body.classList.add('darktheme');
```